# Read a child control with multiple childs with classes having the same name?

Tags: c#, gettext, spy++

I am currently trying to get the text of a control and while going down from the top window to the control I needed I got stuck in this control which has multiple chield with 2 controls having the same class name.

Debug sample code as illustration:

```
IntPtr window = FindWindow("MainControl", "WindowTitle");
iData.Text += window.ToString("X") + Environment.NewLine;

IntPtr control = FindWindowEx(window, IntPtr.Zero, "CMainWindow", null);
iData.Text += control.ToString("X") + Environment.NewLine;

IntPtr control2 = FindWindowEx(control, IntPtr.Zero, "My_SplitterWindow", null);
iData.Text += control2.ToString("X") + Environment.NewLine;

IntPtr control3 = FindWindowEx(control2, IntPtr.Zero, "ATL:0061FA08", null);
iData.Text += control3.ToString("X") + Environment.NewLine;

IntPtr control4 = FindWindowEx(control3, IntPtr.Zero, "ATL:0061E168", null);
iData.Text += control4.ToString("X") + Environment.NewLine;

IntPtr control5 = FindWindowEx(control4, IntPtr.Zero, "ATL:00620118", null);
iData.Text += control5.ToString("X") + Environment.NewLine;

IntPtr control6 = FindWindowEx(control5, IntPtr.Zero, "ATL:00622208", null);
iData.Text += control6.ToString("X") + Environment.NewLine;

// stucked here... :/
```

Here is an image of the child control I am at right now:
[image: child control with multiple controls]

**I need from `ATL:00622208` exactly the 2nd control `#32770 (Dialog)` but how do I read only the second one using FindWindowEx to move to the next control ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the window handle 'IntPtr' you can get the list of child windows like this...

```
IntPtr window = FindWindowEx("MainControl", "WindowTitle");

IntrPtr child = GetWindow(window, GW_CHILD | GW_HWNDFIRST);
while(child != IntPtr.Zero)
{
     child = GetWindow(child, GW_HWNDNEXT);
}
```

You can find the pinvoke needed for the Win32 GetWindow from [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindow.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as you can see i am getting the child of the child of the child would how that be in the context you are saying ?

Comment: I have tried using Control.FromHandle and FromChildHandle but both always fail, window does have the window handle but c is always null.

Comment: Seems I was wrong. The FromHandle only works when .NET already has a control associated with that handle which is not the case for you. I have updated the response to use a different approach.